# Line chart in c# using data from database

Tags: c#, line

i want to plot a line ghraph in c# windows application.
where X axis has date values & Y axis has integer/double (eg. 'rate of items') values.
& i can get this data from database firing some query.
how can i plot the line graph for these date & rate combination???????

Comment: you can directly bind the values using IDE in the properties of chart, as it is a c# desktop application. explore in the properties pane of charts

Answer (score 3):

you can use [microsoft chart controls](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31397/New-Microsoft-Chart-Controls-for-Web-and-Windows-F)

[Samples](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4418)

[Getting Started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456753.aspx)

[Line Chart settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489252.aspx)

If you are also exploring commercial libraries, you can use [Xceed chart controls](http://xceed.com/Chart_WinForms_Intro.html). Xceed library is very easy to use, and produces wonderful effects in no time.

Comment: please send any proper site / answer